# How to add command line argument help to python script?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a python script where using the following command in command line I can run the script:

```
python3 myprogramname.py –in_file input.fasta –out_file output.fasta –unk_file unknown.fasta –n_mismatch 3 –min_len 150 -forward GTGCCAGCMGCCGCGGTAA -reverse ACAGCCATGCANCACCT
```

For this I am trying to set up the arguements such that if the following command is used the help output can aid the user:

```
python3 myprogramname.py -help
```

I have the following script so far but there are errors that I cannot seem to fix:

```
from sys import argv, exit

import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog="arg.py", usage="%(arg.py)s [options]")

#Mandatory arguments
parser.add_argument("--in_file", help = "The name of the input FASTA file.")
parser.add_argument("--out_file", help = "The name of the trimmed reads file.")
parser.add_argument("--unk_file", help = "The name of the file containing unprocessed reads.")
parser.add_argument("--n_mismatch", help = "The tolerance for mismatches in the forward or reverse primer sequence.")
parser.add_argument("--min_len", help = "The minimum length a sequence must be in order to be processed")
parser.add_argument("--h", help = "Insert helpful information.")

#Parse arguments
args = parser.parse_args()

parser.print_help()
```

Ideally the output of `python3 myprogramname.py -help` should produce the following:

```
usage: myprogramname.py -in_file <inputfile> -out_file <outfile> -unk_file <unknownfile> -n_mismatch <mismatchnumber> -min_len <minimumsequencelengthnumber> -forward <forwardprimerstring> -reverse <reverseprimerstring>

required arguments:
--in_file The name of the input FASTA file
--out_file The name of the trimmed reads file
--unk_file The name of the file containing unprocessed reads
--n_mismatch The tolerance for mismatches in the forward or reverse primer sequence
--min_len The minimum length a sequence must be in order for it to be processed
--h The help information for your program
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/argparse.py", line 1775, in parse_known_args
    namespace, args = self._parse_known_args(args, namespace)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/argparse.py", line 1981, in _parse_known_args
    start_index = consume_optional(start_index)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/argparse.py", line 1889, in consume_optional
    raise ArgumentError(action, msg % explicit_arg)
argparse.ArgumentError: argument -h/--help: ignored explicit argument 'elp'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "arg.py", line 18, in <module>
    args = parser.parse_args()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/argparse.py", line 1743, in parse_args
    args, argv = self.parse_known_args(args, namespace)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/argparse.py", line 1782, in parse_known_args
    self.error(str(err))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/argparse.py", line 2400, in error
    self.print_usage(_sys.stderr)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/argparse.py", line 2370, in print_usage
    self._print_message(self.format_usage(), file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/argparse.py", line 2336, in format_usage
    return formatter.format_help()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/argparse.py", line 291, in format_help
    help = self._root_section.format_help()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/argparse.py", line 222, in format_help
    item_help = join([func(*args) for func, args in self.items])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/argparse.py", line 222, in <listcomp>
    item_help = join([func(*args) for func, args in self.items])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/argparse.py", line 308, in _format_usage
    usage = usage % dict(prog=self._prog)
KeyError: 'arg.py'
```

Comment: How many of those unspecified "errors that [you] cannot seem to fix" go away once you spell "argument" correctly?

Comment: @jwodder i've fixed the spelling, thank you for that I've edited my post. When I try to type in `python3 myprogramname.py -help` I still get errors like `File "arg.py", line 18, in <module>
    args = parser.parse_args()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1701, in parse_args
    args, argv = self.parse_known_args(args, namespace)` where arg.py is the name of my script.

Comment: Please paste the complete error message into your question.

Comment: Why cannot you instantiate the parser as `parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()`?

Comment: @dedObed that seems to have worked in solving the errors but I wanted to customize the "usage=" line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`usage`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#usage) keyword to `ArgumentParser` only allows a `%(prog)s` format specifier.  `%(arg.py)s` is not a valid format specifier.  Either write `usage='arg.py [options]'` or write `usage='%(prog)s [options]'`.